# c# unit testing method that calls EF Core extension method

Tags: c#, unit-testing, asynchronous, mocking, moq

I've been trying to unit test this simple method:

```
public void DeleteAllSettingsLinkedToSoftware(Guid softwareId)
{
    _dbContext.Settings.Where(s => s.SoftwareId == softwareId).ForEachAsync(s => s.IsDeleted = true);
    _dbContext.SaveChanges();
}
```

However I'm having a hard time unit testing this method from the moment the `ForEachAsync()` method gets called.

So far I've used Moq to setup the dbContext to return the proper settings when the `Where()` is executed. 
My attempt:

```
Setup(m => m.ForEachAsync(It.IsAny<Action<Setting>>(), CancellationToken.None));
```

My question is: How will I unit test the call to the `ForEachAsync()` method?

I've read online that some people say it's impossible to unit test some static methods, if that's true in my case I'm curious about alternatives to test as much of this method as possible.

**Edit**

My complete test code:

```
[TestMethod]
public async Task DeleteAllSettingsLinkedToSoftware_Success()
{
    //Arrange
    var settings = new List<Setting>
    {
        new Setting
        {
            SoftwareId = SoftwareId1
        },
        new Setting
        {
            SoftwareId = SoftwareId1
        },
        new Setting
        {
            SoftwareId = SoftwareId1
        },
        new Setting
        {
            SoftwareId = SoftwareId2
        }
    }.AsQueryable();

    var queryableMockDbSet = GetQueryableMockDbSet(settings.ToList());
    queryableMockDbSet.As<IQueryable<Setting>>()
        .Setup(m => m.Provider)
        .Returns(new TestDbAsyncQueryProvider<Setting>(settings.Provider));

    DbContext.Setup(m => m.Settings).Returns(queryableMockDbSet.Object);

    _settingData = new SettingData(DbContext.Object, SettingDataLoggerMock.Object);

    //Act
    var result = await _settingData.DeleteAllSettingsLinkedToSoftwareAsync(SoftwareId1);

    //Assert
    DbContext.Verify(m => m.Settings);
    DbContext.Verify(m => m.SaveChanges());
    Assert.AreEqual(4, DbContext.Object.Settings.Count());
    Assert.AreEqual(SoftwareId2, DbContext.Object.Settings.First().SoftwareId);

}
```

I am aware that my Assert still needs more checks.

The GetQueryableMockDbSet method:

```
public static Mock<DbSet<T>> GetQueryableMockDbSet<T>(List<T> sourceList) where T : class
{
    var queryable = sourceList.AsQueryable();

    var dbSet = new Mock<DbSet<T>>();
    dbSet.As<IQueryable<T>>().Setup(m => m.Provider).Returns(queryable.Provider);
    dbSet.As<IQueryable<T>>().Setup(m => m.Expression).Returns(queryable.Expression);
    dbSet.As<IQueryable<T>>().Setup(m => m.ElementType).Returns(queryable.ElementType);
    dbSet.As<IQueryable<T>>().Setup(m => m.GetEnumerator()).Returns(() => queryable.GetEnumerator());
    dbSet.Setup(d => d.Add(It.IsAny<T>())).Callback<T>(s => sourceList.Add(s));
    dbSet.Setup(d => d.AddRange(It.IsAny<IEnumerable<T>>())).Callback<IEnumerable<T>>(sourceList.AddRange);
    dbSet.Setup(d => d.Remove(It.IsAny<T>())).Callback<T>(s => sourceList.Remove(s));
    dbSet.Setup(d => d.RemoveRange(It.IsAny<IEnumerable<T>>())).Callback<IEnumerable<T>>(s =>
    {
        foreach (var t in s.ToList())
        {
            sourceList.Remove(t);
        }
    });

    return dbSet;
}
```

Comment: Why did you choose not to implement the deletion with a regular foreach loop ?

Comment: @Spotted I like the syntax of this linq foreach loop because it makes the code shorter. I understand that some people don't like it because it can make your code look less readable.

Comment: It also greatly decrease the code testability, hence the fact that you are now facing a testing problem due to the implementation you "arbitrarily" choose. I would let you with [this article](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2009/05/18/foreach-vs-foreach/) from Eric Lippert which may (or not) change your opinion about `foreach`.

Comment: @Spotted I might actually agree with you and Eric Lippert on this. But still I think it's interesting to find out how to properly test this method.

Comment: Ok I will write an answer for that.

Comment: Does `IsDeleted` comes from EF or is it something you created ?

Comment: Something I created

Answer (score 4):

You don't have to mock `ForEachAsync` at all. `ForEachAsync` returns `Task` and is being execute asynchronously this is the source of your problem.

Use `async` and `await` keywards to solve your problem:

```
public async void DeleteAllSettingsLinkedToSoftware(Guid softwareId)
{
    await _dbContext.Settings.Where(s => s.SoftwareId == softwareId)
                             .ForEachAsync(s => s.IsDeleted = true);
    _dbContext.SaveChanges();  
}
```

**Edit:**

The new exception occurs because the supplied `Provider` is not a [IDbAsyncQueryProvider](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn314429.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).

Microsoft implemented a generic version of this interface: `TestDbAsyncQueryProvider<TEntity>`. Here is the implementation from the link:

```
internal class TestDbAsyncQueryProvider<TEntity> : IDbAsyncQueryProvider 
{ 
    private readonly IQueryProvider _inner; 

    internal TestDbAsyncQueryProvider(IQueryProvider inner) 
    { 
        _inner = inner; 
    } 

    public IQueryable CreateQuery(Expression expression) 
    { 
        return new TestDbAsyncEnumerable<TEntity>(expression); 
    } 

    public IQueryable<TElement> CreateQuery<TElement>(Expression expression) 
    { 
        return new TestDbAsyncEnumerable<TElement>(expression); 
    } 

    public object Execute(Expression expression) 
    { 
        return _inner.Execute(expression); 
    } 

    public TResult Execute<TResult>(Expression expression) 
    { 
        return _inner.Execute<TResult>(expression); 
    } 

    public Task<object> ExecuteAsync(Expression expression, CancellationToken cancellationToken) 
    { 
        return Task.FromResult(Execute(expression)); 
    } 

    public Task<TResult> ExecuteAsync<TResult>(Expression expression, CancellationToken cancellationToken) 
    { 
        return Task.FromResult(Execute<TResult>(expression)); 
    } 
} 

internal class TestDbAsyncEnumerable<T> : EnumerableQuery<T>, IDbAsyncEnumerable<T>, IQueryable<T> 
{ 
    public TestDbAsyncEnumerable(IEnumerable<T> enumerable) 
        : base(enumerable) 
    { } 

    public TestDbAsyncEnumerable(Expression expression) 
        : base(expression) 
    { } 

    public IDbAsyncEnumerator<T> GetAsyncEnumerator() 
    { 
        return new TestDbAsyncEnumerator<T>(this.AsEnumerable().GetEnumerator()); 
    } 

    IDbAsyncEnumerator IDbAsyncEnumerable.GetAsyncEnumerator() 
    { 
        return GetAsyncEnumerator(); 
    } 

    IQueryProvider IQueryable.Provider 
    { 
        get { return new TestDbAsyncQueryProvider<T>(this); } 
    } 
} 

internal class TestDbAsyncEnumerator<T> : IDbAsyncEnumerator<T> 
{ 
    private readonly IEnumerator<T> _inner; 

    public TestDbAsyncEnumerator(IEnumerator<T> inner) 
    { 
        _inner = inner; 
    } 

    public void Dispose() 
    { 
        _inner.Dispose(); 
    } 

    public Task<bool> MoveNextAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken) 
    { 
        return Task.FromResult(_inner.MoveNext()); 
    } 

    public T Current 
    { 
        get { return _inner.Current; } 
    } 

    object IDbAsyncEnumerator.Current 
    { 
        get { return Current; } 
    } 
}
```

Now in the `Setup` you'll have to use it like:

```
mockSet.As<IQueryable<Setting>>() 
       .Setup(m => m.Provider) 
       .Returns(new TestDbAsyncQueryProvider<Setting>(data.Provider));
```

Comment: You'd also have to make your unit test use async/await and rather than being "public void" it would be public async Task

Comment: @mark_h Yes you are right if this method returns a `Task` instead of `void`. it seems like that the OP was looking for a solution for the "`ForEachAsync`" problem... +1 from me :)

Comment: you are quite right, this method would have to return a Task. I would point out to the OP that it is considered best practice to do so (avoiding async void where possible). If this does indeed need to be async void then the test would be async void too.

Comment: When i remove the mocking of the foreachAsync I get the error "The source IQueryable doesn't implement IAsyncEnumerable<Setting>"

Comment: @Jeroen I edited my answer to answer your new problem

Comment: I have my mockSet setup just like your edit but I'm still getting the same error.

Comment: @Jeroen add your complete UT otherwise nobody will be able to help you...

Comment: @Jeroen replace`dbSet.As<IQueryable<T>>().Setup(m => m.Provider).Returns(queryable.Provider);` in `GetQueryableMockDbSet` with `queryableMockDbSet.As<IQueryable<Setting>>()
        .Setup(m => m.Provider)
        .Returns(new TestDbAsyncQueryProvider<Setting>(settings.Provider));`

Comment: I just tried that by commenting out the code from GetQueryableMockDbSet and adding that line in my test method and it doesn't work.

Comment: @Jeroen you need to replace only this line not comment out the entire method

Answer (score 2):

Disclaimer: I won't provide a direct solution, as requested by OP because I believe this question is a [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/). Instead I will focus my answer on why is this code so damn hard to test, because yes, more than 30 lines of "arrange" to test 2 lines of code means that something went very wrong.

### Short answer

This method doesn't need to be tested, at least at the unit level.

### Long answer

The problem with the current implementation is a mix of concern.

The first line: `_dbContext.Settings.Where(s => s.SoftwareId == softwareId).ForEachAsync(s => s.IsDeleted = true);` contains business logic (s.softwareId == softwareId, s.IsDeleted = true) but also EF logic (_dbContext, ForEachAsync).

The second line: `_dbContext.SaveChanges();` contains only EF logic

The point is: such methods (that mix concerns) are hard to test at the unit level. Hence the fact you need mocks and several dozens of "Arrange" code to test only 2 lines of implementation !

Based on this constatation you have 2 options:

1. You delete your test because the method is mainly containing EF logic which is useless to test (see [this great series of articles](https://enterprisecraftsmanship.com/2015/06/29/test-induced-design-damage-or-why-tdd-is-so-painful/) for more details)
2. You extract business logic and write a real (and simple) unit test

In the second case, I would implement this logic so that I would be able to write a test like that:

```
[Test]
public void ItShouldMarkCorrespondingSettingsAsDeleted()
{
    var setting1 = new Setting(guid1);
    var setting2 = new Setting(guid2);
    var settings = new Settings(new[] { setting1, setting2 });

    settings.DeleteAllSettingsLinkedToSoftware(guid1);

    Assert.That(setting1.IsDeleted, Is.True);
    Assert.That(setting1.IsDeleted, Is.False);
}
```

Easy to write, easy to read.

How about the implementation now ?

```
public interface ISettings
{
    void DeleteAllSettingsLinkedToSoftware(Guid softwareId);
}

public sealed class Settings : ISettings
{
    private readonly IEnumerable<Setting> _settings;
    public Settings(IEnumerable<Setting> settings) => _settings = settings;
    public override void DeleteAllSettingsLinkedToSoftware(Guid softwareGuid)
    {
        foreach(var setting in _settings.Where(s => s.SoftwareId == softwareId))
        {
            setting.IsDeleted = true;
        }
    }
}

public sealed class EFSettings : ISettings
{
    private readonly ISettings _source;
    private readonly DBContext _dbContext;
    public EFSettings(DBContext dbContext)
    {
        _dbContext = dbContext;
        _source = new Settings(_dbContext.Settings);
    }
    public override void DeleteAllSettingsLinkedToSoftware(Guid softwareGuid)
    {
        _source.DeleteAllSettingsLinkedToSoftware(softwareGuid);
        _dbContext.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

With a solution like this, each concern is separated which allows to:

- Get rid of mocks
- Really unit test business-logic code
- Gain in maintainability and readability

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. For now I've converted the method to use a normal foreach loop. I will discuss your solution with my coworkers

Comment: How would you do this if you wanted to use ForEachAsync()?

Comment: @Jeroen I won't use it anyway because right after you need to call `_dbContext.SaveChanges()` which defeats the whole purpose of calling `ForEachAsync()`.